# Change some parts of anchor "onclick" attribute from inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I need to change the onclick attribute in the  link using the text inputs Name and Phone. I planned to do this with Jquery. I used the keyup function and I understand how to change the attribute with 1 field, but I can't figure out how to use 2 or more fields?

```
<input id="name" type="text">
<input id="phone" type="text">
<a id="paybtn" onclick="ipayCheckout({
  amount:50,
  currency:'USD',
  order_number:'',
  description: 'Description from input name + input phone'},
  function(order) { showSuccessfulPurchase(order) },
  function(order) { showFailurefulPurchase(order) })"
  class="btn btn-primary text-white">Submit
</a>

<script>
  $(function(){

    var title = $('title').text(); 
    var name = $("#name").val(); // How to get and set this value on keyup?
    var phone = $("#phone").val(); // How to get and set this value on keyup?

    $("#paybtn").attr("onclick","ipayCheckout({ amount:50, currency:'USD', order_number:'', description: '" + title + name + phone + "'}, function(order) { showSuccessfulPurchase(order) }, function(order) { showFailurefulPurchase(order) })");

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, you can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dwm8t5v6/).

Comment: @Swati It works! Thanks a lot!